# changing the tweet button's name?

Tags: html, button, twitter, share

i want to chnage the text on the tweet button, from `tweet` to `tweet Now!`

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet Now!</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

i tried to change on this script given to me by twitter, but it deosnt change! someone please help thanks

Comment: Let's the see the script you are currently using.

Comment: its thier thats the little script thier!! :)) @cjm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter don't allow you to do this with the tweet button, as per their guidelines:

```
Tweet button: The button should be displayed and labeled as "Tweet" if the content is being posted exclusively to Twitter, or "Update" if directing to other services in addition to Twitter.
```

see http://dev.twitter.com/pages/display_guidelines

However, you can create your own Tweet button, see http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button#build-your-own-example which you can then style yourself. Try

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #custom-tweet-button a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 20px;
    background: url('http://a4.twimg.com/images/favicon.gif') left center no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
<div id="custom-tweet-button">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button" target="_blank">Tweet this</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have “pretty-printed” (by hand) the script; you might get an idea what to change there, if you want to emulate the function by yourself.

```
var twttr = window.twttr || {};
( function()
{
    if ( !twttr.widgets )
    {
        twttr.widgets = {}
    }

    if ( !twttr.widgets.host )
    {
        twttr.widgets.host = "platform{i}.twitter.com"
    }

    if ( typeof twttr.widgets.ignoreSSL === "undefined" )
    {
        twttr.widgets.ignoreSSL = false
    }

    function T ( X )
    {
        var Z = M( X );
        var Y = twttr.widgets.host;
        var W = Y.replace( "{i}", G++ );

        if ( G == 3 )
        {
            G = 0
        }

        return Z + "://" + W
    }

    function M ( W )
    {
        return ( window.location.protocol.match( /s\:$/ ) || W ) && !twttr.widgets.ignoreSSL ? "https" : "http"
    }

    function S ( a )
    {
        var X;
        for( var W in a )
        {
            X = N.apply( this, W.split( "." ) );
            for( var Y = 0, Z; ( Z = X[Y] ); Y++ )
            {
                new a[W](Z).render()
            }
        }
    }

    function I ( b )
    {
        var Y;
        var Z;
        var X = function ()
        {
            if( document.readyState == "complete" )
            {
                Y()
            }
        };

        var W;
        var a = function()
        {
            try
            {
                document.documentElement.doScroll( "left" );
                Y()
            }
            catch( c )
            {}
        };

        if ( window.addEventListener )
        {
            Y = function()
            {
                if ( !Z )
                {
                    Z = true;
                    b()
                }

                window.removeEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", Y, false );
                window.removeEventListener( "load", Y, false )
            };

            window.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", Y, false );
            window.addEventListener( "load", Y, false )
        }
        else
        {
            if( window.attachEvent )
            {
                W = window.setInterval( a, 13);
                Y = function()
                {
                    if ( !Z )
                    {
                        Z = true;
                        b()
                    }
                    window.clearInterval( W );
                    window.detachEvent( "onreadystatechange", X );
                    window.detachEvent( "onload", Y )
                };

                window.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", X );
                window.attachEvent( "onload", Y )
            }
        }
    }

    function N ( W, a )
    {
        var Z, b = [], X, Y;
        try
        {
            if ( document.querySelectorAll )
            {
                b = document.querySelectorAll( W + "." + a )
            }
            else
            {
                if ( document.getElementsByClassName )
                {
                    Z = document.getElementsByClassName( a );
                    for ( X = 0; ( Y = Z[X] ); X++ )
                    {
                        if ( Y.tagName.toLowerCase() == W )
                        {
                            b.push( Y )
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Z = document.getElementsByTagName( W );
                    var d = new RegExp( "\\b"+a+"\\b" );

                    for ( X=0; ( Y = Z[X] ); X++ )
                    {
                        if ( Y.className.match( d ) )
                        {
                            b.push( Y )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( c )
        {}

        return b
    }

    function Q ( W )
    {
        return encodeURIComponent( W ).replace( /\+/g,"%2B" )
    }

    function D ( W )
    {
        return decodeURIComponent( W )
    }

    function J ( Y )
    {
        var X = [];
        for ( var W in Y )
        {
            if ( Y[W] !== null && typeof Y[W] !== "undefined" )
            {
                X.push ( Q( W ) + "=" + Q( Y[W] ) )
            }
        }

        return X.sort().join( "&" )
    }

    function P ( Z )
    {
        var b = {}, Y, a, X, W;
        if ( Z )
        {
            Y = Z.split( "&" );
            for ( W=0; ( X = Y[W] ); W++ )
            {
                a = X.split( "=" );
                if ( a.length == 2 )
                {
                    b[ D( a[0] ) ] = D( a[1] )
                }
            }
        }

        return b
    }

    function F ( X, Y )
    {
        for( var W in Y )
        {
            X[W] = Y[W]
        }

        return X
    }

    function R ( X )
    {
        var W;
        if ( X.match( /^https?:\/\// ) )
        {
            return X
        }
        else
        {
            W = location.host;
            if ( location.port.length > 0 )
            {
                W += ":" + location.port
            }
            return [ location.protocol, "//", W, X ].join( "" )
        }
    }

    function A ()
    {
        var W = document.getElementsByTagName( "link" );
        for ( var X = 0, Y; ( Y = W[X] ); X++ )
        {
            if ( Y.getAttribute( "rel" ) == "canonical" )
            {
                return R( Y.getAttribute( "href" ) )
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    function K( Y )
    {
        var Z = [];
        for ( var X = 0, W = Y.length; X < W; X++ )
        {
            Z.push( Y[X] )
        }
        return Z
    }

    function C()
    {
        var X = document.getElementsByTagName( "a" ), d = document.getElementsByTagName( "link" );
        var W = /\bme\b/, Z = /^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?twitter.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$/, c = K(X).concat( K( d ) );
        var b, f, Y;

        for ( var a = 0, e; ( e = c[a] ); a++ )
        {
            f = e.getAttribute( "rel" );
            Y = e.getAttribute( "href" );
            if ( f && Y && f.match( W ) && ( b = Y.match( Z ) ) )
            {
                return b[2]
            }
        }
    }

    var E = document.title, L = encodeURI( location.href ), G = 0;
    var U = {
        en: {
            vertical: [ 55, 62 ],
            horizontal: [ 110, 20 ],
            none: [ 55, 20 ] },
        it: {
            vertical: [ 55, 62 ],
            horizontal: [ 110, 20 ],
            none: [ 55, 20 ] },
        es: {
            vertical: [ 64, 62 ],
            horizontal: [ 110, 20 ],
            none: [ 64, 20 ] },
        ja: {
            vertical: [ 80, 62 ],
            horizontal: [ 130, 20 ],
            none: [ 80, 20 ] },
        de: {
            vertical: [ 67, 62 ],
            horizontal: [ 110, 20 ],
            none: [ 67, 20 ] },
        fr: {
            vertical: [ 65, 62 ],
            horizontal: [ 110, 20 ],
            none: [ 65, 20 ] } };
    var H = {
        en: 1,
        es: 1,
        ja: 1,
        fr: 1,
        de: 1,
        it: 1 };
    var B = {
        vertical: 1,
        horizontal: 1,
        none: 1 };
    var V = {
        en: "Twitter For Websites: Tweet Button",
        fr: 'Twitter pour votre site web : bouton "Tweeter"',
        de: "Twitter fÃ¼r Webseiten: Tweet-SchaltflÃ¤che",
        es: "Twitter para sitios web: BotÃ³n para Twittear",
        ja: "WEBã‚µã‚¤ãƒˆå‘ã‘Twitter: ãƒ„ã‚¤ãƒ¼ãƒˆãƒœã‚¿ãƒ³",
        it: "Tweeter per i siti web: Bottone Tweet" };

    twttr.TweetButton = function( a )
    {
        this.originElement = a;
        var X = a.href.split( "?" )[1], Z = X ? P( X ) : {};
        var W = Z.count || a.getAttribute( "data-count" ), Y = Z.lang || a.getAttribute( "data-lang" );
        this.text = Z.text || a.getAttribute( "data-text" ) || E;
        this.via = Z.via || a.getAttribute( "data-via" ) || C();
        this.url = Z.url || a.getAttribute( "data-url" ) || A() || L;
        this.statusID = Z.status_id || a.getAttribute( "data-status-id" );
        this.related = Z.related || a.getAttribute( "data-related" );
        this.counturl = Z.counturl || a.getAttribute( "data-counturl" );
        this.searchlink = Z.searchlink || a.getAttribute( "data-searchlink" );
        this.placeid = Z.placeid || a.getAttribute( "data-placeid" );

        if ( !B[W] )
        {
            W = "horizontal"
        }
        this.count = W;

        if ( !H[Y] )
        {
            Y = "en"
        }
        this.lang = Y
    };

    F ( twttr.TweetButton.prototype, {
        parameters: function()
            {
                var W;
                if ( this.statusID )
                {
                    W = { status_id: this.statusID }
                }
                else
                {
                    W = {
                        text: this.text,
                        url: this.url,
                        via: this.via,
                        related: this.related,
                        count: this.count,
                        lang: this.lang,
                        counturl: this.counturl,
                        searchlink: this.searchlink,
                        placeid: this.placeid }
                }
                W._ = ( new Date() ).getTime();
                return J(W)
            },
        render: function()
            {
                if ( !twttr.TweetButton.fragment )
                {
                    twttr.TweetButton.fragment = document.createElement( "div" );
                    twttr.TweetButton.fragment.innerHTML = '<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" tabindex="0" class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-'+this.count+'"></iframe>'
                }
                var X = twttr.TweetButton.fragment.firstChild.cloneNode( false );
                X.src = T() + "/widgets/tweet_button.html?" + this.parameters();
                var Y = U[this.lang][this.count];
                X.style.width = Y[0] + "px";
                X.style.height = Y[1] + "px";
                X.title = V[this.lang];
                var W = this.originElement.parentNode;

                if ( W )
                {
                    W.replaceChild( X, this.originElement )
                }
            } } );

    var O = { "a.twitter-share-button": twttr.TweetButton };
    S( O );
    I( function()
        {
            S(O)
        } )
} () );
```

Answer (score 0):

The widget.js script is probably changing it to tweet. If not something else.

I would suggest you create another script, that verifies onReadyState and after everything is done you change the text to your preference.

Just give the  tag an id and change the innerHTML property on that id!